# Failing to open websocket client connection on both wasm and native builds

Tags: rust, websocket, rust-tokio, rust-wasm, rust-axum

I am building out my first Rust client/server application and struggling to get my client/server talking to each other over a websocket connection.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

### Problem Overview

- I am using [axum](https://github.com/tokio-rs/axum) with [axum-login](https://docs.rs/axum-login/latest/axum_login/#) on the server.
- I am using [reqwest](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/index.html) and [ewebsock](https://github.com/rerun-io/ewebsock) on the clients.
- I am using websockets to transport data between the server and connected clients.
- The client code needs to build and run on wasm **and** native targets.
- Everything works perfectly with the wasm client.
- The native client fails when opening the websocket conneciton with a `401 Unauthorized`.

### Connection process

The first three steps are exactly the same for wasm and native.

**Wasm client (works)**

- Client send HTTP POST request to `http://localhost:8080/login` with login credentials
- Login succeeds.
- Client opens websocket connection via `ws://localhost:8080/websocket` using [ewebsock](https://github.com/rerun-io/ewebsock) crate.
- Connection opens successfully.

**Native client (fails)**

- Client send HTTP POST request to `http://localhost:8080/login` with login credentials
- Login succeeds.
- Client opens websocket connection via `ws://localhost:8080/websocket` using ewebsock crate.
- Connection rejected with a `401 Unauthorized` response.

I can not understand why the `401` is happening *only for the native client*.
I suspect an issue with storing the users authentication cookie but as far as I can tell, [ewebsock](https://github.com/rerun-io/ewebsock) (which depends on [tokio-tungstenite](https://github.com/snapview/tokio-tungstenite)) does not read the browser cookies while opening the websocket connection anyways (?).

Maybe someone who has a working user auth system with an axum web server using websockets as the transport layer could shed some light on how they got things working?

## Relevant dependencies

**Client**

- [reqwest](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/index.html) to make http calls to backend to authorize the user.

  - enabled cookie_store on native
- [ewebsock](https://github.com/rerun-io/ewebsock) to establish a websocket connection once the user has authenticated.

**Server**

- [axum](https://github.com/tokio-rs/axum) (with feature [“ws”])
- [axum-login](https://docs.rs/axum-login/latest/axum_login/#) for authentication.

## Code

Servers main function - axum::Router (paired down):

```
let app = Router::new()
        .route("/websocket", get(websocket_handler))
        .route_layer(RequireAuthorizationLayer::<UserId, User, UserRole>::login())
        .route("/login", post(login_handler))
        .layer(TimeoutLayer::new(Duration::from_secs(4)))
        .layer(auth_layer)
        .layer(session_layer)
        .layer(CorsLayer::permissive())
        .layer(LiveReloadLayer::new())
        .with_state(app_state);

pub async fn websocket_handler(
    ws: WebSocketUpgrade,
    State(app_state): State<AppState>,
) -> impl IntoResponse {
    ws.on_upgrade(|socket| websocket(socket, app_state.websocket_state))
}
```

How can I fix the `401 Unauthorized` response on native?

## Other notes

- If I remove the requirement for authorization, both the wasm and native clients connect successfully.
- I am using [axum_sessions](https://docs.rs/axum-sessions/latest/axum_sessions/) for session management (removed this code from the snippet above).
- I still strongly suspect the issue is with cookie management - but I am not sure how to open this connection elegantly (i.e. using the same code paths) for both wasm and native.

I have tried enabling the `tls` feature on `ewebsock` crate and changing the connection url to wss://localhost/websocket. This fails.

I have tried enabling the [cookie_store](https://stackoverflow.com) in `reqwest` - but this has no effect. I do not beleive there is a way for `ewebsock` to access that information anyways.

Comment: Where is the clients code? Please provide a [mre]. We can't effectively help debug code we can't see.

Comment: According to the documentation for [`ewebsock::connect`](https://docs.rs/ewebsock/latest/ewebsock/fn.connect.html), it uses  the browser's `WebSocket` API, so it has access to the browser's cookie jar. But I don't see any way to give it access to the `reqwest` cookie store on native.

Comment: I think the cookie set by the server during the login request is not included in the subsequent requests, here `WebSocket handshake`. Please check.